# Ajax POST request on https in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, https

I'm trying to make an Ajax POST request in vanilla js (the site dosen't have jquery). I've tried to do something like this, but can't make it work.

```
var params = { name: "Test"};
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.testurl.com/api/test/save', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(reponse);
    }

};
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

I get this error GET https://www.testurl.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fapi%2ftest%2fsave 404 (Not Found)

Do anyone have any idea how to make the AJAX post request work with https in vanilla js?